# How do I properly specify a label for the goto statement?

Tags: c++, goto

I used the `goto` statement in my program. However when I was trying to compile the program an error message showed: `expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int num1, ans;

    cout << "Please input a number: ";
    cin >> num1;

    if(num1 < 10)
        goto tmp;

    printf("Hello.\n");

    :tmp
    printf("World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem. But you should know `goto` is evil and not something anyone should add to their toolbelt, it's just something to be aware of and something to fear when asked to maintain code.

Comment: `goto` is not "evil"; there is no morality involved. That said, *most* problems (with very specific counter-examples) involving `goto` can be solved in cleaner / more maintainable / idiomatic methods..

Answer (score 2):

The colon goes on the other side of the label, like so:

```
tmp:
    printf("World\n");
```

Comment: Sven, the potato goes in the front.